# Mystery constant in an approximation of the number of stabilizer states

Tags: limits, approximation, quantum-computation

The number of n-qubit stabilizer states is:

$$|\text{StabilizerStates(n)}| = 2^n \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (2^{n-k}+1)$$

This is a bit cumbersome, so it's nicer to use this approximation that you get by dropping the +1 in each term of the product:

$$|\text{StabilizerStates(n)}| \approx \sqrt{2}^{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

The true value is always within $\pm50\%$ of this value. In fact, as $n$ increases, the ratio between the approximation and the exact value seems to converge to a constant around 1.19211. Is there a simple expression for this constant in terms of other constants? Similar to the $\sqrt{2 \pi}$ in Stirling's approximation.

```
n    approx_ratio         exact     
0    0.5                  1         
1    0.75                 6         
2    0.9375               60        
3    1.0546875            1080      
4    1.12060546875        36720     
5    1.1556243896484375   2423520   
6    1.1736810207366943   315057600 
7    1.1828504037111998   81284860800
8    1.1874709131006966   41780418451200
9    1.1897901922278464   42866709330931200
10   1.1909520967124438   87876754128408960000
11   1.191533616290917    360118938418219918080000
12   1.1918245180527065   2950814581398894008747520000
13   1.1919700044440704   48352047730802277227336862720000
14   1.192042756519537    1584496604138390624739828991334400000
15   1.1920791347774875   103844738442021844764198912434073907200000
16   1.1920973244615507   13611345246549571280622608248383803312332800000
17   1.1921064194423587   3568159711001983912930094261880820503114794188800000
18   1.1921109669674574   1870750454881230145710119120561495381578055445245952000000
19   1.1921132407386803   1961627770478450543728425287200131704224354222665109856256000000
20   1.1921143776264602   4113835525369964471582242004752905004040921355479025795486695424000000
21   1.1921149460708924   17254685027072394202944227133987137975878860686813810768164619537055744000000
22   1.1921152302932438   144742823364949756734759973178435845495837169546013201147933409094741184675840000000
23   1.1921153724044535   2428381901529255627786036247688771078897978285976424506536729053865655508884827013120000000
24   1.192115443460067    81482980241657907031675119394680521707991005130229061660569243613817582639612341613152174080000000
25   1.1921154789878756   5468230402318068100829143342991616244111659492489854648284878853401039901805670925263253087943393280000000
```

Comment: It seems like the problem can be condensed to: does $\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (1+2^{k-n})$ converge as $n\to \infty$, and if so to what?

Comment: @Semiclassical Right.

Comment: This product can further be written as $\prod_{k=1}^n (1+2^{-k}).$ In this form, WA yields that $\frac14 (-1;1/2)_{\infty}\approx 1.19211$ where $(a;q)_{\infty}$ is a q-Pochammer symbol. So this at least reduces it into special functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazing is
$$\frac 14 \left(-1;\frac{1}{2}\right)_{\infty }=5 \left(\cos \left(\frac{10 \pi }{51}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{10 \pi }{51}\right)\right)+1.10\times 10^{-7}$$
$$\frac 14 \left(-1;\frac{1}{2}\right)_{\infty }=2^{\frac{2+\sqrt{46}}{20 \sqrt{3}}}+7.39\times 10^{-9}$$
which $\cdots\cdots$ does not mean anything.